# Compare two Images in android using opencv

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am using OpenCV for comparing two images in android. I want to use the following function :

[Compare Function](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#compare)

But how to use it in android? Or is there another way to compare images in android using OpenCV. Please help me out. I am very new to OpenCV. Any help would be appreciated. I have gone through many stack questions but could not get what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

Actually i have to make use of the function from the Core OpenCV. i.e.

```
Core.compare(src1, src2, dst, cmpop);
```

I was not aware about this core class.